# Laravel 4.2 using Monolog, how to change log file location

Tags: php, logging, laravel-4, monolog

The project I'm working on is written in Laravel 4.2, and this works in any context:

```
\Log:notice($msg);
```

And by default it goes to:

```
app/storage/logs/log-apache2handler-2017-05-12.txt
```

Which changes each day.

I would really like to send this specific query to `app/storage/logs/mysql.log` - how do I per-log-event specify the file location that a log entry is to go to?